# vim-snippet: after pressing first tab my snippet does not go to next position in snippet

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate

It is a while I am using snippet plugin in vim along with snipMate. I am totally happy with it.

My problem is after pressing the first tab (and autocompletion) I can not jump to next position in a snippet.

I guess maybe some setting in vimrc impede snippet from working.
for example, I want this custom snippet to work properly. It is located in my ./vim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippet/c.snippet

```
# for (custom)
snippet forr
    for (int ${1:i} = ${2:0}; ${3:$1 < 10}; $1${4:++}){
        ${5}
    }
```

my .vimrc is here:
 https://github.com/Aznaveh/defaultSetting/blob/master/.vimrc
my .bashrc is also there if any alias caused the problem.

Comment: I suspect the "(and autocompletion)" part.

Comment: That works fine, for all snippets even for my own crazy custom things. The one I provided is an actual one in snippets folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is YouCompleteMe addon. Here is a line of my .vimrc

```
" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<TAB>"
```

I use Vundle and I had to use :PluginClean to clean that addon